# Override a single Resharper key binding with Visual Studio Key binding

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I want to use visual studio's default `Alt+Down Arrow` key binding instead of Resharper's `Alt+Down Arrow` binding. I am using Resharper key scheme.

I have tried assigning the key binding from Environment > Keyboard and assigned `Alt+Down Arrow` to **Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown** but it is not working.

Comment: I am using VS 2013 with Resharper 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the key binding related to resharper, then in the same window, add that key binding of visual studio.

edit: remove the assigned key for ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextMethod in keyboard tab of options from all Items in the list of shortcuts (text editor, global, ...).
Then assign alt+down to Edit.MoveSelectedLineDown. i just tested this and it is working.

Comment: I want to keep resharper bindings as default key bindings and just override `Alt+Down Arrow`

Comment: see my edit, you can override any keybindings by first removing resharper's key binding.

Answer (score 0):

In `TOOLS` --> `Options` | `Environment`| `Keyboard`

- Select the scope if the shortcut (can be global) in the `use new shortcut in:` combo box
- go in the `Press shortcut keys` text box, perform your key presses (`Alt+Down Arrow`) and select the command you want to assign it to in the list above.
- Click the Assign button
- Click OK